# How to create JButton array?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I have used below code but did not work properly. I have list of `JButton` objects on the panel but could not click on each button individually.

```
for(int i=0; i<udataArr.length(); i++) {
    userBtn = new JButton();
    userLb = new JLabel();

    cur1 = userBtn.getCursor();
    userBtn.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

    Image imgUO =  ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/img-std.png"));
    userBtn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgUO));
    userBtn.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,paddingBorder));
    userLb.setText((String) udataArr.getJSONObject(i).get("user_name"));
    //button[i].setText((String) udataArr.getJSONObject(i).get("user_name"));
    panelLeft.add(userBtn);
    panelLeft.add(userLb);
    panelLeft.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(15));
}
```

[image]

Comment: "did not work properly" doesn't really describe the issue. There's also no indication that you've got an array of JButtons anywhere... did you mean to declare a `JButton[] buttons` variable somewhere?

Comment: JButton[] myArray = new JButton[]{new JButton("first"), new JButton("second")};

Comment: no... I am using single button multiple times the userBtn is JButton. I have used iteration so that i can use it more then one times..       I haveen user array og JButton...

Comment: Then your topic title is just completely irritating.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Note that one component can be added to a maximum of ***one*** container exactly ***one*** time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code to create JButton Array

```
JButton buttons[];
buttons = new JButton[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
}
```